# A clarification regarding dynamic programming.

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

This is a question regarding dynamic programming.

The document to which I am referring is [this](http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-11.pdf) (pg 325). It says that $$v_n(s_n)=\text{Min}\{t_n(s_n)+v_{n-1}(s_{n-1})\}$$

Here $v_n(s_n)$ is the minimum time spent on and after the $n^{th}$ stage.

Doesn't the "Min" function work for at least two values? How does $\text{Min}\{t_n(s_n)+v_{n-1}(s_{n-1})\}$ even make sense??

Comment: You're generally minimizing over your choice for your next state plus the cost of the optimal path from that state to the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think they meant something like $$v_n(s_n)=\text{Min}_{i\leq n}\{t_i(s_i)+v_{i-1}(s_{i-1})\}$$,
or the minimum over all the previous states + cost of next state

Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) to check the possible dyn. prog. relations.